# Cast of generics type to Any?

Tags: generics, swift

I have a class called `Box` with a generics parameter `T`.

For some reason, it's not valid in Swift to cast a `Box<String>` (or any other type, for that matter) to `Box<Any>`.

```
class Box<T> {}

var box: Box<Any>?
box = Box<String>() // 'String' is not identical to 'Any'
```

In Java there is a `?` that represents any type. (`Box<?>`)

What can I do here in Swift?

Comment: I don't know about swift, but that is not what `dynamic` does in C#. You certainly cannot do `List<dynamic> x = new List<string>();`. You can do `IEnumerable<dynamic> x=new List<string>();`, but that isn't the same (covariance).

Comment: Can't you do `var box: any`?

Comment: @Kobi Right, it was the `?`, not `dynamic`

Comment: @FlorianGl Well, if I do that, all the type information is lost

Comment: @NSAddict - I'm pretty sure that's Java.

Comment: @Kobi Haha ok fixed :P

Comment: @NSAddict I dont think there is a generic placeholder. In C# you can't do that either, `?` isn't C# and `dynamic` doesn't work like this. You CAN'T do `List<dynamic> test; test = new List<string>();` Maybe you should post what you want to accomplish, I'm sure there is another way ;)

Comment: @FlorianGl I did something similar in C# a while back, I'm pretty sure there is a way in C#... Sometimes you don't know the type, or you just don't care about it. In my case I only care about the `Box`, and not the type of the `Box`.

Comment: @NSAddict Then create a base class `Box` or interface `IBox` which `Box<T>` implements.

Comment: @FlorianGl That won't work since the relevant methods use the genetic type

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer is: You **cannot** cast `Box<String>` to `Box<Any>` because there is no relationship between them.

[This page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html) is for Java, but it also apply here

> Given two concrete types A and B (for example, Number and Integer), MyClass<A> **has no relationship** to MyClass<B>, regardless of whether or not A and B are related. The common parent of MyClass<A> and MyClass<B> is Object.

Unless you explicit define a relationship. e.g. support implicit conversion operator:

```
class Box<T> {
    func __conversion<U>() -> Box<U> {
        // do whatever required for conversion
        // try reinterpretCast if you can't make type system happy
        // which will give you runtime error if you do it wrong...
        return Box<U>()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, why would you want your `box` variable to be of type `Box<Any>` but to contain an instance of `Box<String>`?

Swift being a type-safe language, you cannot assign to a variable an object that is not of the same type. It's as simple as you cannot do this:

```
var x: Float
x = 2 as Int
```

If you want your `Box` instance to be associated with any object of any class, just declare it like that:

```
var box = Box<AnyObject>?
```

And you will have the `box` instance that I guess you need.

See this link on type safety in Swift: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_443

And this one on the use of `Any` and `AnyObject`: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-XID_492

Hope this helps,

Comment: Comparing `Float` to `Int` is not the same as comparing `Box<String>` to `Box<Any>`. `String` is of type `Any`, which is why you should be able to cast it. This is just an example, if you declare an instance variable, you can't use type inference unless you give it a value right away.

Comment: Well that's it, it is the same thing, `String` is not of type `Any`, it is a base class just as String.

Comment: @Zedenem Type `Any` is what it says. Try this: `var string: Any = "Test"`

Comment: @NSAddict Swift has the concept of safe casting. Going from Any to String is unsafe. There's as? for casts that may fail as per documentation linked to by Zedenem.

Comment: @JanGorman No man, we're going from String to Any, not the other way around. That is a safe cast. Try it yourself.