# Swift generic type that conform to protocol cannot be used to refer protocol?

Tags: generics, swift, protocols

```
import UIKit

protocol Identifiable
{
}

protocol Storage
{
    func test() -> Data<Identifiable>
}

class DiskStorage<T where T:Identifiable, T:NSCoding>:Storage
{
    func test() -> Data<Identifiable>
    {
       return Data<T>() //error: T is not identical to Identifiable
    }
}

class Data<T where T:Identifiable>
{

}
```

I thought it would be possible to use generic type that conform protocol in order to call method that reference that same protocol. How to cast it? Tried almost everything, nothing is working. Maybe I understand something wrong...

Any help on this one guys? Thanks a lot

Comment: maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25014235/642626

Comment: @CodaFi I don't understand what do you mean. My point is that `Data<SomeIdentifiableClass>` have _no_ relationship to `Data<Identifiable>`

Comment: At a minimum, your syntax for T is suboptimal.  You can more simply write `DiskStorage<T: Identifiable, NSCoding> ...`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

try this

```
protocol Identifiable
{}

class Data<T where T:Identifiable>
{}

protocol Storage
{
    typealias Element : Identifiable
    func test() -> Data<Element>
}

class DiskStorage<T where T:Identifiable, T:NSCoding>:Storage
{
    func test() -> Data<T>
    {
       return Data<T>()
    }
}

// from REPL
 32> var s = DiskStorage<Foo>()
s: DiskStorage<Foo> = {}
 33> s.test()
$R0: Data<Foo> = {}
```

---

As I pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25014235/642626), `Data<T>` have *no* relationship to `Data<Identifiable>`. So you can't use `Data<T>` in place that expecting `Data<Identifiable>` and hence the compile error.